# How to make a search button that will search my website?

Tags: php, search, buttons

I want to make a search button that search only within my website.

1. Do I need external PHP or PERL script?
2. Can it done by JavaScript?
3. Or simply by HTML.

I tried to create a form using HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="search" name="banner_search" class="banner-text-box" >
    <input type="submit" name="" value="SEARCH" class="banner-text-btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WordPress's internal search by calling the [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) function:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

`get_search_form()` will use a default HTML form, but you can create your own custom form by adding a `searchform.php` file to your theme.

Comment: can i edit the default search form design ?

Comment: Yes, you can style the existing form with CSS by targeting `.searchform` for the XHTML form or `.search-form` for the HTML5 form (see the user contributed notes under the docs linked to in my answer for details about the different forms). If you need to alter the markup, then you can go with the searchform.php route.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this HTML form to your page

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" class="banner-text-box" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" class="banner-text-btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Refrence:

- [Default HTML Form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/#user-contributed-notes)